# Issues with antijoin in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a following problem:
I have two tables. I would like to drop all rows in TableA that occurs in TableB. In the fisrt stage I would like to mark those rows using this formula:

```py
TableA = pd.DataFrame({'c': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                    'k': [1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    'l': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'd']})
    
TableB = pd.DataFrame(list({'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'}))   

TableA.merge(TableB, on=['c','0'], how='left', indicator=True)
```

But I got this error `KeyError: 'c'`. What is the problem in my code? Thanks

Comment: Use `TableA[~TableA['c'].isin(TableB[0])]`

Comment: @jezrael elegant, thanks!